# Is there _ANY_ method to connect to a mysql server from XULRunner/Firefox add-on?

Tags: mysql, firefox-addon, xulrunner

How to connect to a MySQL Server from a Firefox add-on? Is there a way to connect directly to a mysql server?

I have tried:

- package "MySQLXPCOM" is no longer under active development/outdated
- package "mozdb" is not running
- execution of jar file (from within the add-on) with mysql connector runs not correctly

I do not want to create a PHP script which executes the commands.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the built-in support for js-ctypes in newer versions of Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes

js-ctypes, like the Python ctypes, let's you bind to native C libraries. You could try to create a small set of bindings to the native MySQL library.